# Visualforce: cannot get forcetk.js to work: 401 Error

Tags: jquery, apexrest, forcetk

I'm trying to get a simple example to work with forcetk.js, where I call an apex rest service defined in the same Sandbox as the vf page below.  I've tried different flavors of the URL, but the error event is always called.  I've created remote sites for different versions of the Sandbox' host name, but that hasn't resolved the issue.  When I specify a URL without the domain (a relative URL), I get a 302 error response.  When I use the Location that Salesforce returns for the 302 response, I get a 401 cross-domain script error.  I'm very new to forcetk.js, so its likely I'm doing something simple wrong.  Would someone please take a look at my vf page below and tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jqueryui_1_11_4_custom,'/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.forcetk}"/>

<h1>ForceTK Test Page</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var client = new forcetk.Client('{!$Api.Session_ID}');
    client.yourAjaxNewFunction = function(mediaPlanId){
        //https://somecompany--env--c.cs7.visual.force.com/services/apexrest/mediaPlanDetail?mediaPlanId=2271&pageSize=10&_search=false&nd=1437750768584&rows=10&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc
        //var url = this.instanceUrl + '/services/apexrest/mediaPlanDetail?mediaPlanId=2271&pageSize=10&_search=false&nd=1437750768584&rows=10&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc';
        var url = '/services/apexrest/mediaPlanDetail?mediaPlanId=2271&pageSize=10&_search=false&nd=1437750768584&rows=10&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc';
        j$.ajax({
            async: this.asyncAjax,
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            error: function() { 
                //console.log(error);
                alert ( 'Error!' ); 
                },
            success: function() { alert('hello!'); },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                if (this.proxyUrl !== null) {
                     xhr.setRequestHeader('SalesforceProxy-Endpoint', url);
                }
                //xhr.setRequestHeader(this.authzHeader, "OAuth " + this.sessionId);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer {!$Api.Session_ID}');

                //xhr.setRequestHeader('X-User-Agent', 'salesforce-toolkit-rest-javascript/' + that.apiVersion);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-User-Agent', 'salesforce-toolkit-rest-javascript/' + '22');

            }
        });
    };
</script>

<form action="/">
<input type="button" onclick="client.yourAjaxNewFunction('2271');" />
</form>

</apex:page>
```

**UPDATE**

Following is the latest version of my VP page. When I click the button, my browser is reporting an error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined*

The JavaScript statement reporting this error is in the forcetk.js code

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jqueryui_1_11_4_custom,'/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.forcetk}"/>

<h1>ForceTK Test Page</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var forceTKClient = new forcetk.Client();
    forceTKClient.setSessionToken('{!$Api.Session_ID}');

function callApex(mediaPlanId)
{
    var url = '/mediaPlanDetail' + 
        '?mediaPlanId=' + mediaPlanId + 
        '&pageSize=10' +
        '&rows=10' + 
        '&page=1' + 
        '&sidx=&' + 
        'sord=asc' +
        ''
        ;

        forceTKClient.apexrest(
            url,
            function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log('SUCCESS - ' + data);
            },
            function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('ERROR - ' + textStatus);
            },
            'GET',
            '',
            null,
            false
         );
    };

</script>

<form action="/">
<input type="button" onclick="callApex('2271');" />
</form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: 401 indicates you have are not [authorized](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2).

Comment: I thought the idea of using forcetk.js is that I wouldn't need to authenticate with the other sf domain.  I am passing in a session id when I create the forcetk client.  Why doesn't that work?

Comment: You might want to look at this question to get some further details: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009AtcIAE

Comment: Your not actually setting the session token correctly.

Comment: @techbusinessman I changed my code to fit the example you provided.  I'm getting a different error. I'll update my question to include the new code and the error.

Comment: Can you provide the error message along with the stacktrace? It would be helpful to know which file and line is throwing the error.

Comment: Actually, try removing your var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();. You are no longer using that line and I think it's causing conflicts with the internal forcetk.js library.

Comment: @techbusinessman Commenting the j$ assignment line appears to have worked.  Thanks!  But I guess I'm wondering how this impacts using jQuery on the page. SF recommends using the jQuery.noConflict, but in order to get forcetk.js to work, I can't do that anymore.

Comment: Just change the variable name. You could use jq$ for example.

Comment: I'll update my comments to an answer so others can see this question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reviewing the the following question and answer you will find the correct syntax needed to make the appropriate forcetk.js call: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009AtcIAE

Once that is done, please ensure that you update your jquery noconflict variable to something other than j$ to ensure that you do not have conflicts with the forcetk.js library.

Answer (score 0):

According to the github documentation, access /services/data doesn't require a proxy server, but /services/apexrest does require a proxy.

Your code shows an apexrest endpoint.  Have you set-up a proxy and overridden the cross-domain issue?

I'll download the example from https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit to get that working first before trying yours.

Comment: Can you be more specific by what you're referring with "have you set-up a proxy and overridden the cross-domain issue" I thought the point of forcetk.js was to get around the cross-domain issue between VF pages and Apex web services?